# tflite_runtime interpreter.py" "" is already registered! on Windows 10

Tags: import, wrapper, interpreter, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to import the Tensorflow Lite Runtime Interpreter.  I get the error “ImportError: generic type: type "InterpreterWrapper" is already registered!”.  I have looked at numerous websites with similar error message, but I have not found any resolution.
If I remove the “from pipeline_speak import nmvolcano”,  the program executes successfully. The program receives this error when I add any additional import statements.

Here is the error trace:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
"""
Connect a resistor and LED to board pin 8 and run this script.
Whenever you say "marvin", the LED should flash briefly
"""
import pipeline_speak
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import timeit
import query
import python_speech_features
from pipeline_speak import nmvolcano
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

# Parameters
debug_time = 1
debug_acc = 0
word_threshold = 0.5
rec_duration = 0.5
window_stride = 0.5
sample_rate = 48000
resample_rate = 8000
num_channels = 1
num_mfcc = 16
model_path = 'wake_word_marvin_lite.tflite'

# Sliding window
window = np.zeros(int(rec_duration * resample_rate) * 2)

# Load model (interpreter)
interpreter = Interpreter(model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print(input_details)

def main():
    # Start streaming from microphone
    with sd.InputStream(channels=num_channels,
                        samplerate=sample_rate,
                        blocksize=int(sample_rate * rec_duration),
                        callback=sd_callback):
        while True:
            pass

# Decimate (filter and downsample)
def decimate(signal, old_fs, new_fs):
    # Check to make sure we're downsampling
    if new_fs > old_fs:
        print("Error: target sample rate higher than original")
        return signal, old_fs

    # We can only downsample by an integer factor
    dec_factor = old_fs / new_fs
    if not dec_factor.is_integer():
        print("Error: can only decimate by integer factor")
        return signal, old_fs

    # Do decimation
    resampled_signal = scipy.signal.decimate(signal, int(dec_factor))

    return resampled_signal, new_fs


# This gets called every 0.5 seconds
def sd_callback(rec, frames, time, status):
    # GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.LOW)

    # Start timing for testing
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    # Notify if errors
    if status:
        print('Error:', status)

    # Remove 2nd dimension from recording sample
    rec = np.squeeze(rec)

    # Resample
    rec, new_fs = decimate(rec, sample_rate, resample_rate)

    # Save recording onto sliding window
    window[:len(window) // 2] = window[len(window) // 2:]
    window[len(window) // 2:] = rec

    # Compute features
    mfccs = python_speech_features.base.mfcc(window,
                                             samplerate=new_fs,
                                             winlen=0.256,
                                             winstep=0.050,
                                             numcep=num_mfcc,
                                             nfilt=26,
                                             nfft=2048,
                                             preemph=0.0,
                                             ceplifter=0,
                                             appendEnergy=False,
                                             winfunc=np.hanning)
    mfccs = mfccs.transpose()

    # Make prediction from model
    in_tensor = np.float32(mfccs.reshape(1, mfccs.shape[0], mfccs.shape[1], 1))
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], in_tensor)
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    val = output_data[0][0]
    if val > word_threshold:
        print('marvin')
        nmvolcano()

    if debug_acc:
        print(val)

    if debug_time:
        print(timeit.default_timer() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the imported code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import os, sys
from transformers import pipeline
from query import askQuestion, getAnswer

def nmvolcano():

    # get the volcano corpus
    with open('volcanic.corpus', encoding="utf8") as file:
        context = file.read().replace('\n', '')

    # endless loop - keep soliticitng for questions
    while(True):
        # say greeting
        question = askQuestion()

        # Generating an answer to the question in context
        qa = pipeline("question-answering")
        answer = qa(question=question, context=context)

        getAnswer(answer)
```

Comment: Reconfiguring the RPI, then reinstalling TFLite fixed the issue